# Can not access Azure SQL database after moving Azure API app to custom domain

Tags: azure, ssl, dns, azure-sql-database, azure-api-apps

I moved my API from free plan `app service` to a basic plan `app service` with `custom domain` and `SSL certificate`.

1) I see that my API app's status is "running", Authentication (AAD) is working properly

2) if I open it's api definition (i.e. */swagger/docs/v1) it IS working

3) If i try a request that does not try to access backend Azure sql db, then it is working correctly

4) If I use a request that call backend Azure SQL db (it worked before moving API to custom domain) it fails with this error:

> {"The underlying provider failed on Open., StackTrace:    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean
>   shouldMonitorTransactions)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass65`1.b__63()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String
>   commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions,
>   Object[] parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String
>   commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[]
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass14`1.b__13()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n 
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n
>   at
>   P..Repositories.DataAccessLayer.DbContexts.P..DbContext.GetP..Dtos()\r\n
>   at
>   P..Repositories.Repositories.P..Repository.P..Repository..ctor()\r\n
>   at P..API.Controllers.A..Controller.Get()"}]}

Only thing I've found so far suggests that my API can not access Azure SQL because of firewall rules, but that doesn't sound as an option, since I just assigned a custom domain to my app, I believe it is in the same "place" in Azure... and I did not manage so far to find any suggestions regarding Azure SQL db connections when migrating API to custom domains...

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that by some strange reason, after moving to custom domain - publishing settings, `AzureDatabase` connection string had a non-existent (seams like "generated" name -> Api name with added postfix _db) database name. When I changed it to the real db name, everything started to work again...

P.S. I guess unchecking "use this connection string at runtime (update destination web.config)" would give the same result, since `web.config` holds the right connection string.

[image]